# Interval refresh a static request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I apologize if this seems stupid or redundant, I've search and read related pages with little understanding.

I use this function to call my chat widget to each page. (In case I would like to switch chat server.)

```
<?PHP include "newchat.php"; ?>
```

I would like to refresh newchat.php at an interval of 20 minutes. (To prevent chat time out.)

I use this code on newchat.php, which results in the entire main page to refresh. (ie. index.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(10000);">
*chat script here*
```

I think I may need to put script/ajax on each template page, which tells browser to refresh only that element, however I do not understand this code and am not sure if it applies.

Thank you for reading and help you may provide.

Comment: Instead of including, you possibly make an AJAX request to newchat.php (which performs it's stuff), and then returns what you need?

Comment: If you navigate directly to `newchat.php`, does it work on it's own?

Comment: Remove the `SCRIPT` tag out of your `HEAD` tag. Remove the `onload` from your `BODY` tag. Within your `BODY` tag add a `SCRIPT` tag that contains the following JavaScript code:

`window.setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 10000);`

Are you sure that a complete refresh of the page is what you want, though? You'll lose anything and everything that was tied to the page state...

Comment: Greetings, I am going to try various suggestions.  Thank you for help so far.  Regarding this, there is no info for people to lose as my site has simply a video element and a chat widget.  I am using 10 second refresh as a test, but it eventually will be set to 20 minutes.  This is because chat box goes idle if you do not use it for 25 minutes. I'd like the chat box to always remain viable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your newchat.php file into a iFrame on your pages instead of directly including it. ie:

```
<iframe src="newchat.php" id="chatFrame" frameborder="0" width="YOUR-WIDTH" height="YOUR-HEIGHT">
```

Then you can refresh from with-in the newchat.php file. Or if you want control over it from each page you can use the iframes id to control a refresh from the parent:

```
document.getElementById('chatFrame').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```